# Google Analytics with two different tracking id in iOS(objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

I have two different tracking id UA-xxxx-1, UA-yyyy-2 which has to be implemented for tracking all screen views and event action of that views, i have gone through the goole doc links which have mentioned in all related searches:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/advanced
but this doesn't work for me.

My implementation... Im using google analytics sdk of version 3.13
In Appdelegate.m,

```
*-(Bool)didfinishLaunching {
im initializing the tracker,
// 1
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;     
// 2
[[GAI sharedInstance].logger setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];     
// 3
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;     
// 4
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXXXXX-Y"];
}*
in the same class another method named GAItracking:
*-(void)gaiTracking{
    id<GAI Tracker> tracker1 = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXX-1"];

id<GAI Tracker> tracker2 = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithName:@"Tracker2"
                                                     trackingId:@"UA-XXXX-2"];
id<GA Tracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

[tracker1 set:kGAIScreenName value:@"Home Screen"];
[tracker2 set:kGAIScreenName value:NSStringFromClass([self class])];

[tracker1 send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] build]]; 
 [tracker2 send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] build]];
}*
```

In the view which has to be tracked im setting the screen view as,

```
*id<GAITracker> defaultTracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker]; 
[defaultTracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView]
                        set:@"Home Screen" forKey:kGAIScreenName] build]];*
```

but this above implementation does not work for both tracker id instead it is working for only the 1st tracker id. so kindly guide me to solve this issue for tracking the both id in each view controller.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because it's a singleton.. You won't find a way around this. You may want to revisit your Analytics strategy as this doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Why do you need to report to two different IDs?

Comment: one id is to track for client and another is for development team

Comment: can any onle help to do so

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate your events for some reason, instead of using differents tracking ID, consider using event categories: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/events

Comment: i not geting what exactly i want to do by this evnt implementation. im already using this eventcategory in view controller which i want to track the specific events, but my need is i want to pass two different tracking id in same method

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple tracking id's at the same time, without using default tracker.
Refer the following code:
Do this in appdelegate.m,
set tracker1 and tracker2 id as a string,

```
tracker1 = UA-xxxx-1;
tracker2 = UA-xxxx-2;
```

then have a separate method,

```
-(void)globalTracking(Nsstring *)sendData{
 if (tracker1) {
        [trackerGlobal send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView]
                               set:screenName forKey:kGAIScreenName] build]];
    }
    if (tracker2) {
        [trackerCustom send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView]
                              set:screenName forKey:kGAIScreenName] build]];
    }
```

Now from the viewcontrollers which you want to track,
create the appdelegate instance and call the method globalTracking,

in viewController:

```
AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app sendData:@"screenName"];
```